# PHP downloading image script not works

Tags: php

i am using the below code for downloading an image to my harddisk .By using the first link ,which i have placed in news page,works .i can download an image . the second link which i have placed in gallery  , that is not working . the path is correct and i opened an image with out downlaod.php file ,there is not error in path but the image is not downlaoding . i tried different images using the different image id, but it not works on that perticular page

```
<a href="<?php echo SITE; ?>download.php?filename=<?php echo SITE; ?>uploads/news/<?php echo $rowimg['image']; ?>" title="download">
```

### downloading an image

```
 <a href="<?php echo SITE; ?>download.php?filename=<?php echo SITE; ? >uploads/gallery/<?php echo $row['folder']; ?>/<?php echo $row1['folder']; ?>/<?php echo  $row2['folder']; ?>/<?php echo $rowimg['image']; ?>" title="Download">
download</a>
```

### error is :the file may be corrupted or too big

download.php

```
<?php    
$filename = $_GET["filename"];
$buffer = file_get_contents($filename);
/* Force download dialog... */
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Type: application/image");

/* Don't allow caching... */
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");

/* Set data type, size and filename */
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($buffer));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");

/* Send our file... */
echo $buffer; 
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the error is but I see a *MASSIVE* security whole here, what if I did this.. http://www.blah.com/download.php?filename=database.inc.php

Comment: Well, how big is that image? :p

Comment: You could try adding "\r\n" to all of your headers `header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n");`

Comment: ya your right, i not noticed .. thanks.. is there any code to download only images ?

Comment: @Matthias it is 120kb image..

Comment: And you would get your headers straight. More headers is not better.

Comment: You could blacklist the files I guess `if (preg_match('!(\.php$|\.phtml$)!', $_GET['filename']) exit('Naughty girl!');`

Comment: @Dale whitelist much better :) `$allowed = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png'); $ext = explode('.', $filename); if (!in_array(array_pop($ext), $allowed)) exit();`

Comment: @AlexanderLarikov in this case I agree, just first thing that popped into my head :)

Comment: You should use:  header("Content-Type:" . $extension); $extension="image/jpg" or whatever

Comment: @Dale  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXIT in /home//download.php on line 2

Comment: could you please answer this question without comment ..

Comment: @BalluRocks Use alex's whitelist in this case, and the issue with mine is a missing ) after the if ()

Answer (score 1):

Use `cURL` !

```
$ch = curl_init('http://my.image.url/photo.jpg');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // buffer output (`true` if you will be redirecting stream to the user, in $result will be your image content)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1); // because image is binary data

// Within these two lines you can donwload image directly to the file on your server
// $fp = fopen('/my/saved/image.file', 'w');
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

$result = curl_exec($ch); // executing requrest (here will be raw image data if RETURNTRANSFER == true)
$response_code = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // getting response code to ensure that request was successfull
$content_type = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE); // getting return content-type

// Listing allowed image types    
$allowed_mimes = array(
            'image/jpeg',
            'image/gif',
            'image/png'
            );

if ($response_code == 200 AND in_array($content_type, $allowed_mimes) ) {
  header( 'Content-Type: '.$content_type );
  echo $result; // echoing image to STDOUT
} else
  return false;
```